# java: json parser problem with same strings

Tags: java, json, parsing

I wrote this code:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> listContent2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>>();

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> content() {
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://...");
    try {
        JSONArray hotspots = json.getJSONArray("hotspots");
        HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> mapContentHotspot = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < hotspots.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject e = hotspots.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray actions = new JSONArray(e.getString("actions"));

            for (int j = 0; j < actions.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject e2 = actions.getJSONObject(j);
                HashMap<Integer, String> mapContent = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                switch (e2.getInt("activityType")) {
                    case 27:
                        mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri"));
                    case 2:
                        mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri"));
                    case 1:
                        mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri"));
                    //default:
                        //break;
                }

                mapContentHotspot.put(e.getString("id"), mapContent);
            }

            listContent2.add(mapContentHotspot);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return listContent2;
}
```

to take the content of this json array:
http://pastebin.com/bXfwcQ2U 
The problem is in the section of "actions". I try to take the 3 "uri" but i take only the last one (with the "activityType": "1"). Where is my wrong in my java code? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe mapContent creation should be moved outside of the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add break !!! in your code

```
case 27:
                    mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri"));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri")); 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mapContent.put(e2.getInt("activityType"), e2.getString("uri"));
                    break;
```

Comment: Usually, yes. But in this case it won't make a difference, because all the cases are the same, and idempotent.

Comment: exactly what it says Thilo!! with the "break" it doesn't work!

Comment: @John: You should still have the `break`. Or even better combine the cases into one (to remove code duplication): `case 27: case 2: case1: mapContent.put ... break;`